# Need decay in perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I do not understand why the following code is not valid.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Ts>
void funka( std::tuple<Ts...>&& v ) {    
}

template<typename T>
void funkb( T&& v ) {
    funka( std::forward<T>( v ) );
}

void funk() {
    auto tup = std::tuple<int,int>( 1, 2 );
    funkb( tup );
}
```

It fails with this error:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'void funkb(T&&) [with T = std::tuple<int, int>&]':
<source>:24:16:   required from here
<source>:10:10: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'std::tuple<int, int>&&' to lvalue of type 'std::tuple<int, int>'
     funka( std::forward<T>( v ) );
     ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It compiles if I `forward` with a decay.

```
template<typename T>
void funkb( T&& v ) {
    funka( std::forward<std::decay_t<T>>( v ) );
}
```

So the question is. Why is that not valid code? To me it seems that the resulting parameter type of `funkb` and `funka` is the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: && in funka is an r-value reference and the similar looking && in funkb is a forwarding reference.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is that not valid code?

In the `funkb( tup )` call, `tup` is an *lvalue*. Due to *forwarding reference* deduction rules, the type of the argument `v` in `funka` is deduced as `std::tuple<int, int>&`.

`std::forward<std::tuple<int, int>&>( v )` doesn't move `v` - it still is an *lvalue*.

*Lvalue*s do not bind to *rvalue references*.

---

> It compiles if I forward with a decay.

`std::decay_t` removes all cv-qualifiers and references. It changes your `forward` call to something like: `std::forward<std::tuple<int, int>>( v )`.

When `std::forward` is invoked with a non-reference or an *rvalue reference* as its template parameter, it will move `v`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use decay and pass in an rvalue to `funkb`, then decay does nothing as the type is already "decayed" (i.e. it's `T`).

If you pass in an lvalue however, then the type of the forwarding reference is `T&`, and when you decay that, you get `T`. This means that the result of `std::forward` will be an rvalue in both cases.

Now the code is not valid without decay because `funka` takes a rvalue reference, and you pass an lvalue to `funkb` which you then forward (preserving the value category). You're basically doing

```
int a;
int&& b = a;
```

As you can see, with decay, you will always get an rvalue, which can bind to a rvalue reference.